# By creating a Variable that is defined as a string with a fixed-length, is the used bytes per cell or range?

Tags: string, excel, variables, fixed-length-record, vba

as a relatively new user to Excel, I could not seem to find any confirmation if the a string with a fixed-length has the memory assigned per range or cell.

I am thinking it is per range, because I could not create a string with a fixed-length and set the range as the last cell in a row.

Ex:

```
Dim HilvlActivity as String * 3
HilvlActivitySource = Range("F3", "F:F").End(xlDown).Row
```

And instead, had to use

```
Dim HilvlActivity as String * 5000
HilvlActivitySource = Range("F3", "F:F").End(xlDown).Row
```

So my question is basically: is the assigned fixed-length definition per cell (Ex: F3) or per the entire assigned range?

I may be overthinking this, or should have coded the end of the row more efficiently (will change later). But this is still a basic concept that I want to make sure I understand. Some of the information I have looked into is John Walkenbach's book for Power Programming with VBA, Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/string-data-type), PowerSpreadSheets (https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-data-types/#Long-VBA-Data-Type), but still can't seem to find the correct answer.

Anyone know of any good resources that really dives into variable details, it would be appreciate. Otherwise, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: you dim `HilvlActivity` but you use `HilvlActivitySource` and the length `String * 3` applies to the first but your range is in the second. So your question is not very clear.

Comment: @ PEH Sorry, wrote the range from memory, the string variable name and declared range are supposed to be the same.

Comment: but then you still assign a `.Row` which is a row number to a string, which also doesn't make much sense. Please [edit] and update your question to what you actually mean then.

Comment: @ PEH Hmm, I see what you mean. The row would take the count and not the values of the cells. I was going to have to re-structure the range, but I really appreciate you pointing it out. Thanks!

Comment: Yes and even if you take the values of the range (multiple cells), you cannot push them into 1 string. You would need at least an array for that. I think you are totally up the wrong tree with what you are trying to do and already asked the wrong question. So what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @PEH I am trying to take an entire row whose cells each contain a value mix of letters and numbers (only 3 characters are allowed per cell) and then set the range of that row as the entire row. I was doing arrays but this is a project for another team, and they want everything in variables that are not arrays (or constants). So I am trying trying to minimizing the data type because it is going to be more inefficient by not using arrays.

Comment: @ PEH I believe that @Chronocidal  has answered my question. Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first:  You haven't defined `HilvlActivitySource` as a variable anywhere...

The length of a fixed-length-string is applied to the string variable itself.  For example:

```
Dim HilvlActivity as String * 3
HilvlActivity = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Value
MsgBox Len(HilvlActivity)
```

will **always** show the message `3` - if F3 contains less than 3 characters, then there will be spaces added to the end.  If F3 contains *more* than 3 characters, then only the first 3 will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

`Dim a as String * 10` means that the string `a` will be always of length `10` and if an assigned value goes above this length it will be cut to the first `10` chars.

This illustrates it:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim a   As String * 3
    Dim b   As String
    Dim c   As String * 10

    a = "ABCD"
    b = "ABCD"
    c = "ABCD"

    Debug.Print a                    'ABC
    Debug.Print b                    'ABCD
    Debug.Print Len(c)               '10  
    Range("A1") = StrReverse(c)      '      DCBA in range "A1" with 6 empty spaces upfront

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting, never knew that existed.

Comment: @SJR - this exists for backwards compatibility, I doubt that it can be of any practical use.

Comment: @Vityata that's what I thought, the string is just setting the length per cell in a range, so I am wondering now if the problem is how I declared the range as the entire row. Thanks!

Comment: @BellaS.Holt **No** - the `Range` is **not** having its length set, the `String` variable is.  If you wanted to do that, use Data Validation instead.

Comment: @Chronocidal I am sorry, I am really not approaching this right, so if I say a Dim S as String * 3 and then equal it to a range of an entire row, each cell in the row is set to 3 characters (not the variable) per a cell in the range row? Is that correct?

Comment: @BellaS.Holt No, the `String` variable `HiLvlActivity` is set to a string of the first 3 characters (padded with spaces) of the row *number* the cell.  You want `Dim rCell As Range: For Each rCell In Range("F3",Range("F3").End(xlDown)): rCell.Value = Left(rCell.Value & Space(3),3): Next rCell` to trim the values to the first 3 characters with space-padding at the end

Comment: @Chronocidal, I have not see variables defined that way and definitely need to look into other resources. But the code makes a lot more sense. (kinda like whenever Arthur Doyle explains Sherlock Holmes reasoning for his answer that solved the case). Perfect, thank you!